# Making array equal by lcm

Tags: algorithm, math

Given an array  a1,a2,a3
.. an of size n. With value as ai = i.In one second we can take any two of them and take lcm(ai,aj). We have to find minimum time  to make array equal. Can anyone help what should be its approach?

Comment: I found a series for n=2 , required time is 1, n=3 time required is 2 .for n=4, required time is 3.

Comment: But not able to generalise. Can. Anyone help?

Comment: Anyone please  reply

Comment: Hi @Bindu, make sure your questions are explanatory then only you get answer. Please elaborate a bit more about exactly what you're looking for and may be I will be able to help

Comment: We have to take lcm of any two elements.any modify that elements with it's lcm.

Comment: We have to all elements equal by performing the minimum number of Operation discuss above.

Comment: Did you make an attempt, or are you just asking us to solve it for you?

Comment: I made attempt for n greayer then 4 answer is n itself,I guess

Comment: What does "make array equal" mean? What array, and equal to what?

Answer (score 0):

Search for multiples.

For example, if you have 2 and you have 4, you can ignore any lcm with 2. If you have 2, 4, 8, 16 and 32, you can ignore any lcm that involves 2, 4, 8 and 16, because a lcm that involves 32 would already cover all of the other numbers.

You can find the biggest divisor of a number very fast (in constant time) since your sequence goes straight from 1 to **n** and you know **n** (so a single division **n/i** should tell the biggest divisor of **i**).

Reducing the numbers you need to use will reduce the time you take doing lcms.

---

In a nutshell: for each number `i`, if there is a number `x = k * i` where `k > 1` and `x < n`, you can ignore `i`. This also holds for `x`.